# Looping through the keys of a hashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap called AfricanPeople

```
private HashMap<Integer, Object> AfricanPeople = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
```

the key is the age and the value is a person object.

I want to loop through the hashmaps keys and get all people that are between the age of 30 and 45.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please read the javadoc. Type `HashMap` into google...

Comment: Or, better yet, bookmark [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) so you can find it next time.

Comment: Please always include the info what you tried so far...

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, using

```
for (Integer key : map.keySet())
```

But a HashMap is not the appropriate structure for this. You should use a TreeMap instead, which can [directly return a submap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap%28K,%20boolean,%20K,%20boolean%29) containing the keys between 30 and 45: